# Prove that $ 2^{6ℓ + 2} ≡ 4\pmod{18}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, totient-function

Prove that  $2^{6ℓ + 2}≡ 4 \pmod{18}$
for $0\leℓ ∈ ℤ$.

Comment: Do you mean $2^{6\ell+2}$ or $2^6\ell+2$ or even $2^{6\ell}+2$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, as is [explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). For example, what are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried so far? Where did you encounter this question?

Comment: @Bernard I think it is $2^{6l+2}$ because in the body it is written 2^(6l+2)

Comment: You can use the same methods as in the linked dupe.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Since you tagged [tag:totient-function], note that $\phi(9)=6$, so $2^{6\ell}\equiv1\pmod9$, so $9|2^{6\ell+1}-2$, so $2^{6\ell+2}\equiv4\bmod18$

Comment: More generally, $a^{6+2} \equiv a^2 \bmod{18}$ for all $a \in \mathbb Z$. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Exponential_cycle_length)

Comment: How can I use Euler function in here?

Comment: ברוך הבא.  See the above comments

Comment: TBH can't really see how you moved from the second "so" to the last one.. @J.W.Tanner

Comment: perhaps it would have been more clear had I written $2^{6\ell+1}\equiv2\bmod9$ instead of the equivalent $9|2^{6\ell+1}-2$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner It is okay, but I just can't see how you made the move in the end from mod 9 to mod 18.

Comment: Could you see it if I write $9|2^{6\ell+1}-2$, so $18|2^{6\ell+2}-4$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Mabey you can do me a favor and write down the full answer. I believe your answer is correct but I'm having a hard time understanding the moves.

Comment: I can't post an answer now, because the question has been closed as a duplicate, though I'm not sure my answer would apply to the proposed duplicate; anyway, it might help you to look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2059752/mod-distributive-law-factoring-bmod-ab-bmod-ac-ab-bmod-c/2059937#2059937)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** This follows from the fact that
$$
2^6 \cdot 4 \equiv 4 \pmod{18}.
$$

Comment: More generally, $a^{6+2} \equiv a^2 \bmod{18}$ for all $a \in \mathbb Z$. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Exponential_cycle_length)